# Complex function series.

Tags: complex-analysis

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z)$ is a holomorphic function in an open and connected set D. Prove that if $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{Re} f_n(z)$ is uniformly convergent on any compact set in D, then $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{Im} f_n(z)$ is either uniformly convergent on any compact set or divergent at any point in D.

This statement feels not so true. I don't understand how come $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{Im} f_n(z)$ can diverge and yet $\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_n(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \operatorname{Re} f_n(z) + i \operatorname{Im} f_n(z)$ still converges.

Comment: The way the problem is stated seems very strange. Are you actually given that $\sum f_n$ is a holomorphic function, or does the problem just say that $(f_n)$ is a sequence of holomorphic functions?

Comment: Btw, the sensible version of the problem can't be true unless $D$ is _connected_...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich  $\sum f_n$ is a holomorphic function.

Comment: doesn't the assumption that $\sum f_n(z)$ exist at all imply that $\sum \operatorname{Im} f_n(z)$ converges ?